# Getting Parent Directory for each file from Dir Output

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a directory with multipe levels of folders.
I am completely new to writing batch files and I am writing my first one.
Stuck for ages on trying to

1. find all files in the directory including sub-folder
2. get parent directory for each file
3. save as variable like %parent.filename%

I have been searching here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490909(v=technet.10)

And on Google but unfortunately I am stuck.

So now I managed to save the full path of each file as variable, but I want %Folder.FileName% to return the parent directory only, not the full path.

This is the code I have been testing in the command prompt.

```
For /F %A in ('Dir Linkedin /A-D /s /b /o') do SET Folder.%~nxA=%~pA
```

**EDIT**

I also saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871385/batch-scripting-how-to-get-parent-dir-name-without-full-path?rq=1)

And tried this code:

```
FOR /F %A in ('Dir Linkedin /A-D /s /b /o') do ECHO %~nxA %~pA >>Paths.txt
FOR /F "tokens=1,2" %A in (Paths.txt) do SET Parent.%A=%~nB
```

But `%~nxB` doesn't return any value... I expected it to get the last string of the path.

Comment: Not sure what your question is.  Your code satisfies all three of your bullet points.

Comment: No, I only want the parent directory. Not the full path name.

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /F %A in ('Dir Linkedin /A-D /s /b /o') do ECHO %~nxA %~pA. >>Paths.txt
FOR /F "tokens=1,2" %A in (Paths.txt) do SET Parent.%A=%~nB
```

Note the extra `.`

The path provided by the `~p` modifier terminates in `\` so adding `.` to this means "the directory name itself as though it was a filename"

As a one-line command (within a batch, decorated by standard palaver)

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

FOR /F %%A in ('Dir test* /A-D /s /b /o') do FOR /F %%S in ("%%~pA.") do SET Parent.%%~nxA=%%~nS

set parent.
GOTO :EOF
```

I used the filemask `test*` to better suit my system.

I can't imagine you'd voluntarily perpetually re-type the command, so the format for use within a batch file is shown.

Comment: I think the point being made is with `%~pA`, which contains the fully qualified path minus the drive, e.g. `\path\to\ `, _(when they want `to`)_. To do that you'd need another `For` loop or additional series of `Set` commands.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it did not work. I added the point but it only added a point to each output line.

Basically I would like my loop to set variables like this for each file found using the dir command.
C:\Users\User\Documents\Linkedin\Folder\Subfolder\file1.doc

SET Folder.file1.doc=Subfolder

C:\Users\User\Documents\Linkedin\Folder\file2.doc

SET Folder.file2.doc=Folder

Comment: OK - I've added-in the second line from your original posting.

Comment: Thank you ! It worked perfectly. :)
Is there a way to avoid creating a text file ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do this as a single nested `For` loop from the Command Prompt and with no output file:

```dos
For /F "Delims=" %A In ('Dir /B/S/A-D "Linkedin" 2^>NUL')Do @For %B In ("%~pA.")Do @Set "Folder.%~nxA=%~nxB"
```

From a batch-file, perhaps this would help you out:

```dos
@Echo Off
Rem Remove any existing Folder. variables
For /F "Tokens=1*Delims==" %%A In ('Set Folder. 2^>NUL')Do Set "%%A="

Rem Set the new variables
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/S/A-D "Linkedin" 2^>NUL')Do For %%B In ("%%~pA.")Do Set "Folder.%%~nxA=%%~nxB"

Rem View any returned variables
Set Folder. 2>NUL&&Pause
```